# Error In updating Ms-Access Table from C# Code

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, insert

I am trying to update my Access table from a C# form. When I run the program it runs without any message but when I click on Update it breaks and gives the following error message:

> *Input string was not in a correct format.*
>
> ACCESS TABLE FIELDS:- ID(string), Name(string), Score(int)

Error Message :-

```
 public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
 }

 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Database3.accdb");

 public void UpdateRecord()
 {
        int score = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        **string command = "update score set Name= '"+textBox1.Text+"' , Score= '"+score+"' where ID= '"+textBox3.Text+"'  ";**
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command,conn);
    conn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

public void showData()
{
   string command = "Select * from score";
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, conn);

   OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataTable Table = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(Table);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = Table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Score` is an integer.  You have quotes around it in your string, which is invalid.  Try:

```
string id = textBox3.Text;
string command = "update score set Name= '"+textBox1.Text+"' , Score= "+textBox2.Text+" where ID= '"+id+"'  ";
```

I'd be concerned that you have no data validation in place.  What if they don't enter a number in the text box?  And why are you converting 'ID' to a integer when it's an string field?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i have changed the code, its now giving me another error message. Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("update score set Name= '" + textBox1.Text + "' , Score= '" + textBox2.Text + "' where ID= '" + textBox3.Text + "'  ", conn);
            conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();